# How do I move this light box over a few inches in the wall?

Tags: electrical, light

I need to move the existing power over to where the hole is in the image. There was a strip light and I’m replacing with a single light.
The blue box is anchored to the frame. The cable is too short to feed over.
*I’ll be adding a wood finish to the wall, so the light fitting will anchor on that.

Is there an product that allows one to join electric cables - so that I can make the line longer to fit? Should I remove the blue box and get something else to use on the wall?

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to the attic directly above this celing?

Comment: @bigchief - no i dont

Comment: Tyco, among other manufacturers, makes splice (and tap) kits that meet NEC requirements for use inside a wall, e.g. [these](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Data+Sheet%7FEPP-3384%7F1904%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_DS_EPP-3384_1904.pdf%7FA22899-000).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cable comes in from below, and it appears to be running up the right side of the stud, so I'd bet you can swing it over by releasing some staples below the box.

Since you're overlaying paneling or boards, just cut out a couple horizontal slots in the drywall--one at the box level and one a couple feet lower. These could be 4" high by the width of the stud bay.

Now find and pull the staples. Swing the box over and re-mount it to a new framing block, which could be horizontal between studs.

Whether you replace the drywall cutouts is up to you. It would be easy to float some scrap plywood or 1x2 in there and screw them back into place.